# (C/C++) Initialize and return array in the same line

Tags: c++, arrays, c, casting, return

I was wondering how I could initialize and return an array on the same line using c/c++.

My intuition says that the syntax should look somewhat like this: `return (int8_t*) {hours, minutes, seconds};`

Am I correct? Is the cast mandatory? Or is there another/better way of doing this?

**EDIT:** I'm asking this because I cannot test the code right now. I won't be in front of a computer for some days.

**ANSWER:**

- for C follow the steps in the verified answer
- for C++ you would use a `std::vector` or `std::array` as the return type and then have `return { 1, 2, ..., N };`

Comment: For what it's worth -- it would have been faster just to try it.

Comment: Are you asking for C or C++?  In C++ you would use a `std::vector` or `std::array` as the return type and then have `reutrn { 1, 2, ..., N };`

Comment: why do you need the answer to this *before* you can sit in front of a computer? Sorry, but thats no excuse for the question being unclear. Please include a [mcve] and any compiler errors you get or explain what problem you face with the code

Comment: Also, FWIW, if you have an internet connection you have a compiler.  Here is a few online compilers: [One](https://wandbox.org/), [Two](https://godbolt.org/), [Three](https://ideone.com/l/cpp)

Comment: @NathanOliver I was looking for C++, but a C answer would suffice. Thank you for your answer - it was just what I was looking for.

Comment: consider that your question and answers is not only for you. Future readers will expect either C or C++ answers and they will be disappointed when they find an answer in a different language. You are basically asking two question at once

Comment: You cannot return an array in C (unless it's wrapped inside a struct; but then you return the struct, not the array). The 2nd best thing is to return a pointer to allocated memory (and free that memory afterwards). Also C lines can extend for thousands of characters :-)

Comment: @idclev463035818 I just wanted to know out of curiosity. I never had to code something like that, so I just was wondering how to do it.

Comment: To do it in one line, write a statement to allocate the array, another statement (or several) to fill it in, and another to return it. Put the three statements on one line. Alternatively, do not put too much effort into “stupid programming tricks.” It is nice, to some extent, to find “neat” things in the language, as they may be somewhat associated with understanding the language well and efficiency, but it is a loose association. C has compound literals that can create arrays on the fly, but they would have automatic storage duration in this context, which is not what you want.

Comment: In C, you can create the array as a compound literal `(int8_t []) { hours, minutes, seconds };`, but since the array's lifetime would expire at the end of the enclosing block, any returned pointer to this array's contents would be invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will not work as you expect.

The exact syntax for what you're trying to do would be:

```
return (int8_t []){hours, minutes, seconds};
```

Which creates a **compound literal** of array type.  However, this literal has the lifetime of the enclosing scope.  So when the function returns, the returned pointer is now pointing to invalid memory, and attempting to dereference that pointer invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You'll need to dynamically allocate the memory, then assign each member of the array:

```
int8_t *p = malloc(3 * sizeof(int8_t));
p[0] = hours;
p[1] = minutes;
p[2] = seconds;
return p;
```

Comment: @EricPostpischil Ah yes, updated to take that into account.

Comment: The `malloc` version ought to use `int8_t` for consistency with the original.